# What does "budget return allowance" mean?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, terminology

I have applied for a position in a firm abroad, and in the acceptance email they mentioned that they would provide ***budget return travel allowance***.

Which of the following do you think *budget* most likely implies?

1. A partial reimbursement of my return travel expenses (as defined by some maximum limit). (i.e. *budget* reimbursement)
2. A reimbursement of my *budget* return travel, i.e. economy class travel or equivalent

**EDIT**: The company actually meant #2, as the chosen answer suggests. Thanks.

Comment: It refers to the first definition.

Comment: It probably means that they will reimburse the cost of return travel using budget airlines etc and economy class. Any costs above these would not be reimbursed.

Comment: It could mean either or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably means they will reimburse a budget airline fare - in Europe Ryanair or easyjet, in South-East Asia Air Asia, there are others elsewhere in the world.